# Can AMPL handle this recursively or is a remodeling neccessary?

Tags: ampl

I'm using AMPL to model a production where I have two particular constraints that I am not very sure how to handle.

```
subject to Constraint1 {t in T}:
   prod[t] = sum{i in I} x[i,t]*u[i] + Recycle[f]*RecycledU[f];

subject to Constraint2 {t in T}:
   Solditems[t]+Recycle[t]=prod[t];
```

EDIT: *where x[i,t] is the amount of products from supply point i. u[i] denotes the "exchange rate" of the raw material from supply point i to create the product. I.E. a percentage of the raw material will become the finished products, whereas some raw material will go to waste. The same is true for RecycledU[f] where f is in F, which denotes the refinement station where it has been refined. The difference is that RecycledU[f] has a much lower percentage that will go to waste due to Recycled already being a finished product from f (albeitly a much less profitable one). I.e. Recycle has already "went through" the process of being a raw material earlier, x, but has become a finished product in some earlier stage, or hopefully (if it can be modelled) in the same time period as this. In the actual models things as "products" and "refinement station" is existent as well, but I figured for this question those could be abandoned to keep it more simple.*

What I want to accomplish is that the amount of products produced is the sum of all items sold in time period t *and* the amount of products recycled in time period t (by recycled I mean that the finished product is kept at the production site for further refinement in some timestep g, g>t).

Is it possible to write two equal signs for prod[t] like I have done? Also, how to handle Recycle[t]? Can AMPL "understand" that since these are represented at the same time step, that AMPL must handle the constraints recursively, i.e. compute a solution for Recycle[t] and subsequently try to improve that solution in *every* timestep?

EDIT: The time periods are expressed in years which is why I want to avoid having an expression with Recycle[t-1].

EDIT2: prod and x are parameters and Recycle and Solditems are variables.

Hope anyone can shed some light into this!

Cenderze

Comment: The second constraint makes sense as it represents that "the amount of products produced is the sum of all items sold in time period t and the amount of products recycled in time period t", but could you explain what you are trying to achieve in the first constraint, why does amount of product has to be sum of storage + recycle?

Comment: The first constraint states that in order to produce the required production, prod[t], one can use the "pure" rawmaterial x[i,t] _and_ Recycled material, which is rawmaterial already refined in an adjacent refinement station in the same time period, but used now as an input to create _another_ product in the same time period. Recycle is a finished product in the same time period, BUT it can be used to create more profitable products in the same time period. 

I've updated the Original post to reflect what I mean more, using "exchange rates" of the raw material to create prod[t].

Comment: @vitaut I've edited now and written the edited text in _italic_. The model itself is also somewhat updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two constraints will be considered simultaneously (unless you explicitly exclude one from the problem). AMPL or optimization solvers don't have the notion of time steps and the complete problem is considered at the same time, so you might need to add some linking constraints between time periods yourself to model time periods. In particular, you might need to make sure that the inventory (such as the amount finished product is kept at the production site for further refinement) is carried over from one period to another, something like:

```
Recycle[t + 1] = Recycle[t] - RecycleDecrease + RecycleIncrease;
```

You have to figure out the expressions for the amounts by which `Recycle` is increased (`RecycleIncrease`) and decreased (`RecycleDecrease`).

Also if you want some kind of an iterative procedure with one constraint considered at a time instead, then you should use [AMPL script](http://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/16-script.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The problem with the simplified version is that I want to model that Recycle is the "gap" between items sold and items produced, and that it can be used at the same time period as an input to the production. In practice this model uses more subscripts and such as products where Recycle is a finished product g, which can be used as an input to create the more profitable product p rather than selling it as it is. 

Thank you for providing information regarding scripts. I am reading that link as I write this.

Comment: I've been reading the script section you provided. I am quite unsure if there are any of these scripts you have in mind that may be applicable. As it is now I feel that perhaps a script that reruns the model using other values on Recycle may be useful. Not sure how though, how to alter Recycle to get a better solution. Do you know if these type of scripts can be used using NEOS server?

Comment: @GustavDanell Recycle already represents the difference between sold and produced because you can rearrange the first constraint as Recycle[t] = prod[t] - Solditems[t], or am I missing something? However, the second constraint simply fixes Solditems because x is a parameter, so I'm not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: x is not a parameter, it is a variable which denotes the amount of raw material from a supply i. What is desired is that the program will solve the problem of finding what quantity to sell etc and the Recycle connected to that solution, and then _in the same_ time period add this Recycle in, hence giving a different prod in the initial solution, and a Recycle of 0 due to the Recycle being used now in that time period (in my model, there is a variable "gathering" what is not sold, or Recycled, reused and sold in t as welll).

Comment: I think what you need is to add constraints to carry over inventory (Recycle) between the time periods. I've updated the answer.

Comment: What if I extended my model? Using Recycle[i,j,g,t]
where i declares from which refinement station the product were produced, j declares to which refinement station the product will be taken for futher refinement, p is the end product created at j and t declares the time period.Substituting this into the model (and adapt the model to involve products etc), would this work in the same time period?